# Plupload: get id of file input

Tags: css, prototype, codeception, plupload

I have multiple instances of Plupload included at one page of my application, which are divided in 3 categories and can be added manually by adding a new table row.
I need to test uploading dynamically with Codeception and it's difficult to attach a file to a specific Plupload file input, because you don't know the generated id and it seems not possible to add a certain css class.

I'm trying to get the id of the current Plupload file input by doing:

```
init: {
                Init: function(up) {
                    console.log(up.id); // o_1aa1e71ku20lole1v7s1veqetje0
                    console.log(up.runtime); // html
                }
}
```

The problem is that up.id is not equal to the id of the file input:

```
<input id="html5_1aa1e71krlg119o9ks61uvl17ledv" type="file" style="font-size: 999px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif,application/pdf">
```

How could I get the id to add a custom css class based on the section where it resides? Or do you know another way to target one specific dynamically added Plupload input with Codeception?

Comment: One solution I see is to use JavaScript to make a list of created ids and put those in a hidden input, and/or copy the id into the `name` attribute.

Comment: I need it before uploading. I'm running Codeception's Webdriver to execute an automatically chain test. The problem is that I need Codeception fill the first file input of the second section. Now it's filling the first file input of the first section. The sections as well as the file inputs can be created dynamically, so I'd like to add a css class to the file input to select the first file input with that certain css class. The file upload itself and the other server side actions work perfectly for some years now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value via JS and then use it.

In my case, something like this (my HTML is somehow complicated, but the idea is the same in every case)

```
$profileId = $I->executeJS('return $("#Album_3_idAlbum").parent(".album-no-cover").find(".moxie-shim.moxie-shim-html5").attr("id")');
```